# Is it possible to have a cursor like operation in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am creating a billing application and I am using codeigniter. I have a view where I can view the employee details.In this view file I have a action like delete and edit separately for each employee record. Is is possible to have a single edit button that can edit any employee record that is listed in my view?

**My view file**

```
<table class="resizable" bordercolor="#993300" border="1">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="header">Employee id</th>
                <th class="yellow header headerSortDown">First name</th>
                <th class="green header">Last name</th>
                <th class="red header">Email</th>
                <th class="red header">Emergency contact</th>
                <th class="red header">Category</th>
                <th class="red header">ID card</th>
                <th class="red header">Time in</th>
                <th class="red header">Time out</th>
                <th class="red header">Date of hire</th>
                <th class="red header">Date of termination</th>

                <th class="red header">Date of rehire</th>
                <th class="red header">Reference number</th>
                <th class="red header">Service limitation</th>
                <th class="red header">Chair renter</th>

                <th class="red header">Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach($employee as $row)
              {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_first_name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_last_name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_email_id'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_emergency_contact'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_id_card'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_time_in'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_time_out'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_date_of_hire'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_date_of_termination'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_date_of_rehire'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_reference_num'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_service_limitation'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['chair_renter'].'</td>';



                echo '<td class="crud-actions">
                  <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/employee/update/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">view & edit</a>  
                  <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/employee/delete/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>
                </td>';
                echo '</tr>';
              }
              ?>      
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Here i have a `<a>` to perform edit and delete option. This action passes the id that i choose to edit or delete. Instead of having separate buttons for each employee.I need to have a single button and allow the user to select employee.Like this image[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use JQuery to attach a `selected` class to the row which is clicked via something like:

```
$('tr').on('click', function () {
    // Remove selection from other rows
    $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
    // Add selection to current row
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

That will allow you to place a 'cursor' onto a row, you'll want to style the rows with the `selected` class using CSS or something similar.

Now you can have a single Edit button and use something like the following code to handle the `click` event:

```
$('#edit').on('click', function () {
    if ($('tr.selected').length() == 0) {
        alert('Must select a row!');
    } else {
        // Handle 'edit' event by passing $(this) to whatever you need
        // $(this) will be the currently selected row
    }
});
```

This works since the `$(this)` object acts as a reference to the currently selected row.

Comment: should I add any bootstrap files?

Comment: Depends if you feel the need to use them in your project. This code doesn't explicitly depend on anything other than jQuery, make sure you include it before this code.